# Segfault when using Boost ASIO channels

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to implement coroutine cancellation using channels in Boost::ASIO, however I'm getting segmentation faults and I can't figure out the reason.
I tried using a debugger, but it didn't tell me much, just that the segfault happens after "io_ctx->run()".

Here's my code:

```
boost::asio::awaitable<void> to_be_cancelled(
    boost::asio::experimental::concurrent_channel<void(boost::system::error_code, std::string)>& end,
    shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> io_ctx)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(*io_ctx);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 8000);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(*io_ctx, endpoint);
    co_await
    (
        end.async_receive(boost::asio::use_awaitable_t()) ||
        acceptor.async_accept(sock, boost::asio::use_awaitable_t())
    );

    cout << "done\n";
}

boost::asio::awaitable<void> send_one_message(
    boost::asio::experimental::concurrent_channel<void(boost::system::error_code, std::string)>& channel)
{
    channel.async_send(boost::system::error_code{}, string("hello"), boost::asio::use_awaitable_t());
}

boost::asio::awaitable<void> coroutine_manager(shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_ctx)
{
    auto ch = make_shared<boost::asio::experimental::concurrent_channel<void(boost::system::error_code, std::string)>>(*io_ctx, 5);
    co_await (to_be_cancelled(*ch, io_ctx) && send_one_message(*ch));
}

int main()
{
    auto io_ctx = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>(2);
    co_spawn(*io_ctx, coroutine_manager(io_ctx), boost::asio::detached);
    io_ctx->run();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In general, always include self-contained code in your question (including the includes and namespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a "co_await" in my "send_one_message" function, which I guess meant the string would go out of scope resulting in the receiving channel trying to access freed memory.

Comment: I'd suggest simplifying for style as well. In short, no unncessary dynamic allocations, no passing around of `io_context`, not using deprecated `io_service`, using the MoveAcceptHandler interface for `async_accept`, not spelling out `use_awaitable_t`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88777ab228a4cf5a

Comment: And for flavour, defaulting the completion token to `use_awaitable`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/857edc216a7e5c67

Comment: @sehe Thank you, I'll make the modifications you mentioned.